# Vaadin grid eager loading

Tags: grid, vaadin

Is it possible to force Vaadin 8 grid to load all rows eagerly from backend? Currently it shows only records visible on the screen and fetches next rows on grid scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `grid.setHeightByRows(totalNumberOfItems);` This will cause the grid to show all elements at once, without a scrollbar.

Comment: But I need scrollbar as well.

Comment: That can be achieved for instance by wrapping the grid in a panel,  like this for example `Panel panel = new Panel(grid); panel.setHeight("500px");`

Answer (score 0):

No, the lazy loading behavior is hardcoded into Grid: https://github.com/vaadin/framework/blob/master/client/src/main/java/com/vaadin/client/widgets/Grid.java#L7222-L7224

Edited to add, based on the comment below: not quite hardcoded, but you will still need client-side changes to implement a non-lazy loading Grid (and, as far as I can tell, nobody has actually tried it before).

Comment: It's not fully hardcoded. You can configure the cache strategy through `AbstractRemoteDataSource.setCacheStrategy`. You'd still have to do some workarounds to get to a point where you can pass your own strategy implementation to that method, but it's still doable.